# How do I specify mixed content for the @page{ content: } property?

Tags: css, syntax

I'd like to include an image and some text in the [@top-left](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-page/) box for the @page property, like so:

```
@page {
  @top-left{
    content:url('someurl') + 'some text';
  }
}
```

When I use the above snippet, I get syntax errors. If the error messages are correct, then what's the syntax for this kind of operation?

If the error messages are incorrect, then what is the real issue, and is there a method by which I can get the results I'm looking for?

Comment: What is this `@top-left` thing? Link to reference?

Comment: https://www.google.ca/search?q=page+%40top-left

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can combine images with text in generated content. [CSS2.1's definition of `content`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#content), the one currently implemented by most browsers, does not contain a possible value that combines both an image URI and a string.